# Freeze few column in wxgrid

Tags: wxpython

I have a window that is split to have a custom tree ctrl on left panel and a grid table on the right. Now I want the grid table to display the information in such a way that first few columns freeze (not scroll) while the remaining data has an option to scroll horizontally.
I have no clue how to proceed, please help.
I have seen that splitter window can be of some help, can someone provide a sample code.

Comment: There's an [open issue](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/15169) about it but it has been last modified in 2013 :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that. You would need to use grids and keep them kind of synced. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wxpython-users/Lbt5EW6sRDo

You should ask on the wxPython mailing list too. I swear I saw something on this topic where someone had created some kind of solution, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

wx.FreezeTo(row,col)

0 to unfreeze, otherwise any other number will freeze the first rows or columns