# wxpython,How to freeze first few rows in wx.grid.Grid?

Tags: python, grid, wxpython

I try to make two different classes in order to freeze two rows in the top of grid,like the bottom.
But I found it was very different from what i thought.I just want to freeze two rows like how the Excel do.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOWgM.png)

```
class RightGridTop(grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self,parent,gridwidth):
        grid.Grid.__init__(self,parent,-1)
        self.CreateGrid(2,gridwidth)
        ......

class RightGridBelow(grid.Grid):
    def __init__(self,parent,gridwidth):
        grid.Grid.__init__(self,parent,-1)
        self.CreateGrid(30,gridwidth)
        ......

class OnePanel(wx.Panel):
    ......
    rtpsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    rtpsizer.Add(self.RGridTop,1,wx.EXPAND)
    rtpsizer.Add(self.RGridBelow,1,wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND)
    self.RightTablePanel.SetSizer(rtpsizer)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze few column in wxgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628835/freeze-few-column-in-wxgrid)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/ihrhMajhtXA